# List of WCAG 2.0 AA Guidelines that Wave Firefox Toolbar covers

Tags: firefox, web, accessibility, toolbar, wcag

I am trying to find the WCAG2.0 guidelines covered by Wave firefox toolbar.
I have left a message on the http://wave.webaim.org/ as well and awaiting their reply.
Please let me know if you have already come across the list of guidelines covered and any references to them. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are the guidelines covered by Wave**

- 1.1.1 Non-text Content (Level A)
- 1.2.1 Prerecorded Audio-only and Video-only (Level A)
- 1.2.2 Captions (Prerecorded) (Level A)
- 1.2.3 Audio Description or Media Alternative (Prerecorded) (Level A)
- 1.2.5 Audio Description (Prerecorded) (Level AA)
- 1.3.1 Info and Relationships (Level A)
- 1.4.2 Audio Control (Level A)
- 1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum) (Level AA)
- 2.1.1 Keyboard (Level A)
- 2.1.2 No Keyboard Trap (Level A)
- 2.2.1 Timing Adjustable (Level A)
- 2.2.2 Pause, Stop, Hide (Level A)
- 2.4.1 Bypass Blocks (Level A)
- 2.4.2 Page Titled (Level A)
- 2.4.3 Focus Order (Level A)
- 2.4.4 Link Purpose (In Context) (Level A)
- 2.4.6 Headings and Labels (Level AA)
- 3.1.1 Language of Page (Level A)
- 3.1.2 Language of Parts (Level AA)
- 3.2.2 On Input (Level A)
- 3.3.2 Labels or Instructions (Level A)

This does not mean that Wave handles all the testing you have to do in those guidelines.

WCAG techniques are not normative, and nothing can replace manual, visual or auditive testing.